# Interpreting the results of the paper of Kernalized correlation Filter KCF

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model-evaluation, image-processing

Below is a snapshot of the output of the original paper of KCF.--> open link for full paper
[http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~joao/publications/henriques_eccv2012.pdf](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Ejoao/publications/henriques_eccv2012.pdf)

[image]

[image]

I have two questions:

1-in the first image, what does literally the x-axis mean ? how it should be interpreted?

2- what does it mean **(Tracker precisions at a threshold of 20 (percentage of frames where the predicted location is within 20 pixels of the ground truth)** as shown in the second image

Thanks in advance